# Spring JDBC Query add to map

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

I'm using the Spring JDBC Framework ([like here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_jdbc_example.htm)) to obtain two columns from the database. I have used the 'Mapper' to implement 'RowMapper' class and I execute the query like this:

```
List<Entity> rows = template.query(sql, new EntityMapper());
```

This is my Mapper Class:

```
public class EntityMapper implements RowMapper<Entity> {

@Override
public Entity mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    Entity entity = new Entity();
    entity.setID(rs.getString("ID"));
    entity.setAccount(rs.getString("ACCOUNT"));

    return entity;
}
```

Instead of storing the results of the query into a `<List>`, I want to store them into a `Map` - `accountsById` I created in the same class. I want the ID that goes into the Map to be my key so that I can obtain the Id's with `getID()`

```
 public List<String> getID() {
    if (accountsByID.isEmpty()) {
        return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    } else {
        return new ArrayList<String>(accountsByID.keySet());
    }
}
```

How do I store my query rows into a map in spring and set `ID` as key, with value being `account`.

Comment: try queryForList which will return you a Map object

Answer (score 0):

`queryForList` returns a List of LinkedHashMap objects.

In order to get Map We need to cast the result of `queryForList` method like below

```
       List list = template.queryForList(...);
        for (Object o : list) {
           Map m = (Map) o;
           <your code here which uses Map objects>
        }
```

More about the method  [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcTemplate.html#queryForList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29)